# Why printing dictionary is randomized?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing this code;

```
message='alabama'
random={}
for i in message:

    count={i,4}
    print(count)
```

and the output is

> {'a', 4} {'l', 4} {'a', 4} {4, 'b'} {'a', 4} {4, 'm'} {'a', 4}

every time I run it is giving random sequence. Why does not letters appear in the first place?

Comment: Dictionaries don't retain order, lists do

Comment: Your ´count´ is even a set, but like for dictionaries there isn't a order guaranteed.